# Nginx args rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

This does not work

What am I doing wrong?

```
location / {    
    rewrite ^/companies\?compID=(\d+) /company?compID=$1 permanent;
    rewrite ^/companies\?compID=(\d+)&compName=(.*) /company?compID=$1&compName=$2 permanent;
...
}
```

Comment: You think that query is a part of rewrite uri, but it's not.

Comment: Probably you need `rewrite ^/companies$ /company permanent;`